# Killing processes - AHK

Tags: process, autohotkey

So far I have:

```
Process, Exist notepad.exe
Process, Close, %p_id%
```

How do you set ahk to kill the process if it exists? I read it's something to do with the PID, but don't know how to implement that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at the [Documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Process.htm).

You can kill by simply using the name of the process:

```
Process, Close, notepad.exe
```

If the process does not exist, it will do nothing.

If you still would like to kill the process by using the `pid` instead, you must use the [WinGet](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm) command in order to retrieve the `pid`.

Comment: Doesn't "Process, Exists, ..." write the pid into 'ErrorLevel'?

Answer (score 2):

This AHK script kills the active process when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>:

```
^!k::
{
    WinGet, xPID, PID, A
    Process, Close, %xPID%
}
return
```

Answer (score 2):

there are at least two ways to get the PID from a window that I can think of immediately

1:

```
WinGet, My_PID, PID, WinTitle
```

2:

```
Run, ProgramFilePath "Args", Options, My_PID
```

The first one is to get an already running window PID and the second is to get a PID when opening the program with AHK.  In both cases the variable "My_PID" now contains the window process ID

To answer your question of closing a process if it exists you could try a couple of methods.

```
ifWinExist ahk_pid %My_PID%
    Process, Close, %My_PID%
; OR
Process, Exist, %My_PID% ; from my examples above
;Process, Exist, notepad.exe ; from your example above
If ErrorLevel ; Errorlevel is set to matching PID if found
    Process, Close, %ErrorLevel%
```

I think that should answer your immediate question